# Trying to plot with plt.plot() without success

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph in python and I have defined all x-and y-values in `lst_x` and `lst_y` (made a previous question about that):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_poly(p,x_start=-10,x_end=10,color='b'):

    lst_x = list(range(x_start, x_end + 1))
    print(lst_x)

    lst_y = [eval_poly(p,x) for x in lst_x]
    print(lst_y)

    return plt.plot(lst_y, lst_x, 'b')
    plt.show()

    # eval_poly is another function which produces all y-values for all x:
    
    # def eval_poly(p,x): 
        # ans = 0
        # for degree,coeff in enumerate(p):
        # ans += coeff*x**degree # ekvationen som ska räknas
        # return ans
```

But when trying to perform this I only get:

```
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[102, 83, 66, 51, 38, 27, 18, 11, 6, 3, 2, 3, 6, 11, 18, 27, 38, 51, 66, 83, 102]
Out[265]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x126e4e0d0>]
```

The printed lists have the correct values, but it doesn't plot. and I don't understand why because I have `plt.show()` which otherwise is usually the reason why it does not work?

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: Please  fix the indentation on the code, it isn't easy to follow. Thanks!

Comment: plt.show() is outside the function? I'm guessing you call the function somewhere below plt.show()?

Comment: @Guimoute I use Python.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn My apologize, this is fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: what is eval_poly?

Comment: @Sandsten I tried moving it above return but I got the same message. I call the function in the console-box as `plot_poly(p,x_start=-10,x_end=10,color='b')`

Comment: plt.show() should be called after plt.plot(). So maybe you could try not returning plt.plot() and call plt.show() after plt.plot has been executed?

Comment: @the_gañañufla eval_poly is a function which produce all y-values from all x-values. I edited the text so it makes more sense.

Comment: @Sandsten I tried this but then I, unfortunately, only get out the lists I asked for.

Comment: It works for me when I use a jupyter notebook. Are you just calling the script from the command line with ```plot_poly(p,x_start=-10,x_end=10,color='b')```? There might be minimized plots in your taskbar? Try google for how to show plot in a separate window or something similar.

Comment: @Sandsten thank you! I will do that! Yes I am calling the script from the command line with `plot_poly(p,x_start=-10,x_end=10,color='b')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement terminate the function without calling the show function:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
def plot_poly(p,x_start=-10,x_end=10,color='b'):

    lst_x = list(range(x_start, x_end + 1))
    print(lst_x)

    lst_y = [eval_poly(p,x) for x in lst_x]
    print(lst_y)

    plt.plot(lst_y, lst_x, 'b')
    return plt.show()
```

Comment: This worked in the end and return was probably the big problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the return in the function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_poly(p,x_start=-10,x_end=10,color='b'):

    lst_x = list(range(x_start, x_end + 1))
    print(lst_x)

    lst_y = [eval_poly(p,x) for x in lst_x]
    print(lst_y)

    plt.plot(lst_y, lst_x, 'b')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Your plotted data is backwards.